# angular unit test http request issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to write a unit test for my http request

In my controller, I have something like

```
     $scope.test1 = function(url) {
         productFactory.getProduct(url)
             .then(function(products){
                 $scope.result = products;
              })
    }
```

In my unit factory file

```
    angular.module('myApp').factory('productFactory', function($http) {
        var factoryObj = {};
        factoryObj.getProduct = function(url) {
            return http.get('/product/' + url)
        }
        return factoryObj
    })
```

in my unit test, I am not sure how to write the test because url is dynamic

```
describe('test here', function () {
var testCtrl, scope, httpBackend, mockFactory;

// Initialize the controller and a mock scope
beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _$rootScope_, _$httpBackend_,  _productFactory_) {
    scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    mockFactory = _productFactory_;

    testCtrl = _$controller_('testCtrl', {
        $scope: scope
    });


// the url is dynamic so I am not sure what to write here.

   var url = 12345 <----dynamic product id
   httpBackend.whenGet('/product/' + url).response({'name':'product1'}) 
   var promise = mockFactory.getProduct('/product/' + url);
   promise.then(function (prod) {
       var products = prod;
   });
   $httpBackend.flush();
   expect(products).toBeTruthy();
}));
```

When I run the test, I got

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET /product/undefined
Expected GET /product/12345
```

I am not sure how to write a http request in my case. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you testing, the controller or the `productFactory`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're wanting to test the `productFactory` and not the controller. The only test I can see is to ensure that the appropriate HTTP request is made.

```
describe('productFactory test', function() {
    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    it('getProduct requests /product/:id', inject(function($httpBackend, productFactory) {
        var id = 123;
        $httpBackend.expectGET('/product/' + id);

        productFactory.getProduct(id);
        $httpBackend.flush();
    }));
});
```

Also, you have a typo in `productFactory.getProduct`. It should be `$http.get`, not `http.get`.

---

Say your factory uses a *cookie* service to fetch the ID. Something like this...

```
.factory('productFactory', function($http, cookieService) {
    return {
        getProduct: function() {
            return $http.get('/product/' + cookieService.getProductid());
        }
    };
});
```

You would then test it like this (assuming jasmine v2)...

```
describe('...', function() {
    var cookieService;

    beforeEach(module('myApp', function($provide) {
        $provide.value('cookieService',
            cookieService = jasmine.createSpyObj('cookieService', ['getProductId']));
    });

    it('...', inject(function($httpBackend, productFactory) {
        cookieService.getProductId.and.returnValue(123);
        $httpBackend.expectGET('/product/123');

        productFactory.getProduct();
        expect(cookieService.getProductId).toHaveBeenCalled();

        $httpBackend.flush();
    }));
});
```

Comment: Thanks Phil! Just wondering what if my getProduct function doesn't take id as a param and get id from a cookie. How would you do it? +1

Comment: Basically my problem is that I got Error: Unexpected request: GET /product/undefined because my actual getProduct function doesn't know the id.

Comment: Ideally, your factory would use another service to read the value from a cookie (or similar). You would then mock and inject that service in your test. I'll provide an example